MS Entra Groups: how to get Group Name from Object Ids out of claims in JwtSecurityToken
I created some groups in MS Entra, so I know Name and Object Id of them, and assigned them to my user.
Then, running my REST API, I can get a JwtSecurityToken.
In this token I find claims containing the expected Group Ids the user is member of.
But how do I get the Group Names from these IDs?
I've read hundreds of posts and articles, I tried

SecurityIdentifier(groupId).Translatetypeof(NTAccount))
I worked with DirectorySearcher()
I tried PrincipalSearchResult groups = user.GetAuthorizationGroups();
but all of these seem to work only with SIDs, not with the Object Ids I get from the token.

For my small test case I could just build a lookup table, but the customer is going to create a large number of groups ( > 1000), and the group name contains information I have to evaluate in the application.
Some posts from 2019 tell this is not possible, but propose to vote for this feature, but looking for this I end up with dead links.
But hey, we have 2024, I am sure they created a solution in the meantime ;-)

Have you tried this rest api ? it is simple to get group name via objectId https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

AFAIK you cannot get Group Names in jwt decoded token as Group Names can be changed/same. Its possible to get GroupIDs only. To fetch Group Name by passing GroupID you can make use of Microsoft Graph API query GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/GroupID

Thank you all, so I have to learn MS-Graph.
The initial tutorial from MS is working (after updating the included packages), but has no groups, my first attempts to insert the tutorial code to my test project (with groups) leads to different problems, so I have to deep dive into the basics of Graph...

@Martin Please check the answer below for more in detail


Note that: It is not possible to get Group Names in access token/JWT token as Group Names can be changed and can be same. To fetch Group Name by passing Group ID you can make use of Microsoft Graph API.

You can get Group IDs only as the claim in jwt token:

Generated access token for sample by using below parameters:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
scope:api://xxx/test.read 
grant_type:authorization_code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret
code:code


The Group IDs are displayed:

Hence as a workaround you can make use of Microsoft Graph API to query Group Name by passing Group ID:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/GroupID


